# Counting up an index for empty values and more in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to solve this problem and searching the internet for several days now but have no clue how to do it right.. Maybe someone here can give me a hint or tell me if it is even possible to solve with XSLT 1.0.

### Problem

I need an XSL transformation (XSLT 1.0) to be completed with the following things:

**Filling the empty values of „CALLOUT“:**

- „Empty" CALLOUTS have to be filled with an "Index" 17.1 … 17.2
- Callouts need to be filled with the value of the next CALLOUT <> "" and extended with an index.
- Example: Next filled CALLOUT = "2" will result in "2.1", next empty value "2.2" and so on until the next filled value of CALLOUT is reached

**Filling the field "YCSPOSNO_PI":**

- Default value is "CALLOUT"+"A"
- If there are „Index-Callouts“ the value needs to be „counted up“: 17A … 17B … 17C until the "original" value without index is reached - the original value will be the last counted up character, e.g. 17C.

**Filling the field „EXPLA“:**

- For an „Index-Callout“ (so all fields of CALLOUT with an index value added) all lower "LEVEL_NO" have to be concatenated into this field

--> Example for EXPLA:
LEVEL_NO            CALLOUT     EXPLA
1                  17.1         17.1 = 17.2 + 21
2                  17.2         17.2 = 17 + 18 + 19 + 20
3                  17
3                  18
3                  19
3                  20
2                  21

EXPLA for 17.1 = "17.1 = 17.2 + 21"
(because always LEVEL_NO + 1 of actual LEVEL_NO belong to the actual LEVEL_ONE; 17.1 has LEVEL_NO "1" so all LEVEL_NO "2" below until the LEVEL_NO changes to "1" the next time belong to this one)

EXPLA for 17.2 = "17.2 = 17 + 18 + 19 + 20"
(17.2 has LEVEL_NO "2", so all LEVEL_NO "3" until the next occurance of LEVEL_NO "1" belong to this one)

### Source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns:MT_FlatFile_Lists_Cu xmlns:ns="urn:las:pp:ss1:tar">
<Cu_Records>
    <Record>
        <ESN>123</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>1</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT></CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>123</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>2</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT></CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>123</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>3</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT>3</CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>123</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>3</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT>4</CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>123</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>2</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT>5</CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>456</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>1</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT></CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>456</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>1</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT></CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>456</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>2</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT>17</CALLOUT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <ESN>456</ESN>
        <GRAPHIC_NAME>2.png</GRAPHIC_NAME>
        <LEVEL_NO>2</LEVEL_NO>
        <CALLOUT>18</CALLOUT>
    </Record>
</Cu_Records>
</ns:MT_FlatFile_Lists_Cu>
```

### Desired Output

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<YCSMST01>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <SNDPOR/>
      <SNDPRT/>
      <SNDPRN/>
      <SNDLAD/>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>123#1</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>3.1</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>3A</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA>3.1 = 3.2+5</EXPLA>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>123#1</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>3.2</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>3B</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA>3.2 = 4+5</EXPLA>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>123#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>3</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>3C</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA/>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>123#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>4</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>4A</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA/>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>123#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>5</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>5A</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA/>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
  </IDOC>
</YCSMST01>
<YCSMST01>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <SNDPOR/>
      <SNDPRT/>
      <SNDPRN/>
      <SNDLAD/>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>456#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>17.1</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>17A</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA>17.1 = 17+18</EXPLA>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>456#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>17.2</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>17B</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA>17.2 = 17+18</EXPLA>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>456#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>17</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>17C</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA/>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
      <YCSSTKLID>456#2</YCSSTKLID>
      <CALLOUT>18</CALLOUT>
      <YCSPOSNO_PI>18A</YCSPOSNO_PI>
      <EXPLA/>
    </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
  </IDOC>
</YCSMST01>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsltc="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/xsltc" xmlns:map="java.util.Map" xmlns:dyn="com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfiguration" xmlns:key="com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfigurationKey" xmlns:ns="urn:las:pp:ss1:tar" exclude-result-prefixes="xs ns xsl map key dyn xsltc">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="a" match="Record" use="ESN"/>
    <xsl:key name="b" match="Record" use="concat(ESN, '#', GRAPHIC_NAME)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:MT_FlatFile_Lists_Cu/Cu_Records/Record[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('b', concat(ESN, '#', GRAPHIC_NAME)))]" mode="head"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Record" mode="head">
    <xsl:variable name="stueckliste" select="concat(ESN, '#', GRAPHIC_NAME)"/>
        <YCSMST01>
            <IDOC BEGIN="1">
                <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
                    <SNDPOR/>
                    <SNDPRT/>
                    <SNDPRN/>
                    <SNDLAD/>
                </EDI_DC40>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns:MT_FlatFile_Lists_Cu/Cu_Records/Record[concat(ESN, '#', GRAPHIC_NAME) = $stueckliste]" mode="pos"/>
            </IDOC> 
        </YCSMST01> 
    </xsl:template>
                
                
    <xsl:template match="Record" mode="pos">                
                
                <!-- Segment YCSMOTOR_STKL01 -->
                <YCSMOTOR_STKL01 SEGMENT="1">
                    <YCSSTKLID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(ESN,'#',substring-before(GRAPHIC_NAME, '.'))"/>
                    </YCSSTKLID>
                    <!-- Fill Callout into <CALLOUT> -->
                    <xsl:variable name="callout" select="CALLOUT"/>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <!-- Take value of CALLOUT if CALLOUT has a value -->
                        <xsl:when test="$callout and (not($callout = ''))">
                            <CALLOUT>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$callout"/>
                            </CALLOUT>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <!-- Apply-templates to get next filled Callout value -->
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Record[CALLOUT != ''][1]" mode="nextCallout"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <YCSPOSNO_PI></YCSPOSNO_PI>
                    <EXPLA></EXPLA>
                </YCSMOTOR_STKL01>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Template to get next filled CALLOUT -->
    <xsl:template match="Record" mode="nextCallout">
        <xsl:variable name="nextCallout" select="CALLOUT"/>
        <CALLOUT>
            <xsl:value-of select="$nextCallout"/>
        </CALLOUT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sry it's corrected now.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and reduce the examples to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Oh I didn't know that - I'll take care the next time

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **minimized** stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="pre" match="Record[CALLOUT='']" use="generate-id(following-sibling::Record[CALLOUT!=''][1])" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="Cu_Records/Record[CALLOUT!='']">
            <xsl:variable name="preceding" select="key('pre', generate-id())" />
            <xsl:variable name="callout" select="CALLOUT" />
            <!-- process preceding siblings -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$preceding">
                <item>
                    <callout>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$callout"/>
                        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </callout>
                    <posno>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$callout"/>
                        <xsl:number value="position()" format="A"/>
                    </posno>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- add the current record -->
            <item>
                <callout>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$callout"/>
                </callout>
                <posno>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$callout"/>
                    <xsl:number value="count($preceding)+1" format="A"/>
                </posno>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>       
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <item>
    <callout>3.1</callout>
    <posno>3A</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>3.2</callout>
    <posno>3B</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>3</callout>
    <posno>3C</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>4</callout>
    <posno>4A</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>5</callout>
    <posno>5A</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>17.1</callout>
    <posno>17A</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>17.2</callout>
    <posno>17B</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>17</callout>
    <posno>17C</posno>
  </item>
  <item>
    <callout>18</callout>
    <posno>18A</posno>
  </item>
</output>
```

This should answer your first two questions (which is one more than it should). Please ask your third question separately (I couldn't understand it anyway).

---

Note that this assumes that the last `Record` does not have an empty `CALLOUT`.

Comment: This looks good, thank you! I failed on integrating this logic into my xsl for the position() part but I will continue trying,